# Highstock - Display last chart point in the center of the Y axis

Tags: highcharts

I want to display last chart point in the center of the Y axis always. To do this I use setExtremes() function. With integer values this solution works fine. But then it comes to float values it doesn't.

https://jsfiddle.net/antongrinenko/jj33wd2p/1/

```
$(function () {
$('#chart').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'SomeData',
        data: [[1, 1.1111], [2, 2.2222], [3,3.3333]]
    }],
    yAxis: {
        floor: 0
    }
});

var newValue = 2.82654;
var series = $('#chart').highcharts().series[0];

series.addPoint([4, newValue]);

var extr = series.yAxis.getExtremes();
var delta = Math.max(extr.dataMax - newValue, newValue - extr.dataMin);
series.yAxis.setExtremes(newValue - delta, newValue + delta);
});
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by default options `yAxis.startOnTick` and `yAxis.endOnTick` (both set to true) - Highcharts are rounding extremes to start/end on a "nice-number" tick. You can disable that by setting those option to `false`, see: https://jsfiddle.net/jj33wd2p/2/